# Select and Convert bytes object from a list

Tags: python, ldap, certificate, openldap

I have tried everything in my mind but wasn't successfull. Can anybody help me to select bytes object from a list bellow?

```
[('uid=xxxxxx,o=center', {'userCertificate;binary': [b'0\x82\x07q0\x82\x05Y\xa0\x03\x02\x01\x02\x02\x10`\ .....']})]
```

This is the result from a openldap search and I want to select the userCertificate part of the entry and convert it to a base64 text. When I manually select only the bytes object - the b'0\x82\x07q0\x82\x05Y\xa0\x03\x02\x01\x02\x02\x10`\ .....' section I am able to convert it with base64.b64encode(bytes_variable) into a certificate string, but I have to automatize the selection of this bytes object. I have tried to convert this list into string and use regex to pickup only the part with b'', but then I am not able to convert it to correct certificate format. Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @anothervictimofthemouse I want to take the certificate b'0\x82\x07q0 .....'  (I think this is the DER format) and convert it to PEM. But I am not able to select it from the list, which is the result of the LDAP query, and convert it with this base64.b64encode which I know that works, when I manually select the certificate. I don't know what is the right approach for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a Python list containing a single tuple. The 2nd element of that tuple is a dictionary. That dictionary has a single key. Its value is a list containing one item.

So...

```
list_ = [('uid=xxxxxx,o=center', {'userCertificate;binary': [b'0\x82\x07q0\x82\x05Y\xa0\x03\x02\x01\x02\x02\x10']})]

bytes_object = list_[0][1]['userCertificate;binary'][0]
```

**Note:**

bytes truncated to make this syntactically correct

Comment: Wou, that was fast, thank you. Now it works without any problem :)